# How to use Tensorflow Dataset interleaving to load remote dataarrays in parallel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use Tensorflow's `Dataset.interleave()` to load some data from a remote server in parallel, which is a suggested use-case from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#sequential_interleave).

I have a `DataStreamer` class that opens the stream and which provides a `_generator()` method. My `get_data()` function uses this to create a `Dataset`:

```py
def get_data(year: int, month: int) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    """Get data for a given year and month."""
    data_streamer = DataStreamer(year, month)

    # Create a dataset
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        data_streamer._generator,
        output_signature=(
            (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(12,), dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(12, 128, 128), dtype=tf.float32)),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(48,), dtype=tf.float32),
        ),
    )
```

I have another function, `get_many_data()`, which is supposed to interleave these datasets:

```py
def get_many_data(years: list[int], months: list[int]) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    """Interleave datasets to get data across many months and years."""
    expanded_years = []
    expanded_months = []
    for year, month in itertools.product(years, months):
        expanded_years.append(year)
        expanded_months.append(month)

    date_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((expanded_years, expanded_months))
    return date_dataset.interleave(
        lambda year, month: get_data(year.numpy(), month.numpy()),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
    )
```

Note I have to use `year.numpy()` and `month.numpy()` because the `DataStreamer` uses these in formatting the URLs and in slicing the data (using `calendar.monthrange`). The problem is that `.interleave()` doesn't use eager execution so I get an `AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`.

How can I change this code to maybe use eager execution just for the data loading? Or is there a way to make this work without changing the execution mode? Many resources I've found suggest using `tf.py_function()`, but it's not clear how to use this for `.interleave()` rather than `.map()`.